# PHP header call two times when download from mobile

Tags: php, header, http-headers

i have a download.php file as below. when i click to download.php page from PC internet browser then it's works fine and send a single request. But when i click the same page from my mobile device then it send TWO request.

```
$filename ="test.mp3";
LogWriter($filename);
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
```

Log File when i click from PC:

> Time: 2014-12-23 13:20:24|| Message: test.mp3

Log File When i Click the same file from Mobile Device:

```
Time: 2014-12-23 13:31:24|| Message: test.mp3
Time: 2014-12-23 13:31:28|| Message: test.mp3
```

Any idea?Please help.

Comment: We need to see the code that sends the request, not the script that responds.

Comment: this is the full code just have an extra LogWrite Function as below:function LogWriter($log_message)
{

$time_value = (date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Dhaka") * 120);
       $current_time = date("H:i:s",time() + $time_value);
    $hour=substr($current_time,0,2);    
    $text_file_name=date('d-m-Y')." ".$hour.".txt";           
    $current_date_time=date('Y-m-d')." ".$current_time;   
    $fp = fopen($text_file_name,'a');
    $writing_info="Time: ".$current_date_time."|| Message: ".$log_message."\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $writing_info);
    fclose($fp);
    
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a session that told you have requested a seconds ago

```
session_start();
$filename ="test.mp3";

if(!empty($_SESSION['download_'.$filename]) &&
     (time() - $_SESSION['download_'.$filename) < 10)) exit;
// Check, then exit if you have requested before in 10 seconds

$_SESSION['download_'.$filename] = time();
LogWriter($filename);
header("Pragma: public"); // required
header("Expires: 0");
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
header("Cache-Control: private",false); // required for certain browsers 
header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($filename)."\";" );
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile("$filename");
```

**Note:** But you can't mistakes it server-side. Because this is client-side problem

Comment: thanks for your suggestion. But the code will be used in a  commercial site and each second file download request comes. So, it will be difficult to implement this type of code.

Comment: why ? `$_SESSION` appears differently for every users. user A and user B will have different result if you use `$_SESSION`

Comment: your solution is correct. no other option to prevent this double request. anyway , i this we can use session_id() value instead of 'download_' session name. Because same file can be requested on same time by different user. please see my edit on your answer. please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: yes, i got it. but every user have different PHPSESSID. So don't worry about it. cause `$_SESSION` use browser cookie. just use my code and you will satisfied